# C#: Cannot see the changes in the windows registry

Tags: c#, regedit

No error, no exception, no nothing. Everything seems to be OK, except that the registry remain as it is.

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Edit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Restore(); // not included in the sample for simplicity
            }
        }

        public static void  Edit()
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey Login;
            Login = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Login"].ToString());
            Login.SetValue("ServerName", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"].ToString());
            Login.SetValue("ImageServerName", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageServerName"].ToString());
            Login.Close();

            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey Login2;
            Login2 = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Wow6432NodeLogin"].ToString());
            Login2.SetValue("ServerName", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Wow6432NodeServerName"].ToString());
            Login2.SetValue("ImageServerName", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Wow6432NodeImageServerName"].ToString());
            Login2.Close();
        }
}
```

I think there's is an error somewhere. But no exception is thrown. The catch block never gets hit.

I'm running it as Admin. I even ran it with no admin privileges, but still no errors when it supposed to show "access denied" or something. I restarted the laptop to see the changes applied, but still no success.

I used this code to read the recently added values and I can see the keys. But somehow the changes are not being applied.

```
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Login"].ToString());
        Object o = key.GetValue("ServerName");
        Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
```

I'm using .Net 4.5.2, building for Any CPU, SO: Windows 7.

Do I need to commit the changes or something?

Comment: You're probably getting an error.  You should edit your code so that you can see what the error is.

Comment: That's what I think, but the console shows no error. The catch block never get hit.

Comment: How do you know? Your code gives you no way of knowing whether the `catch` block gets hit.

Comment: I debugged the code.

Comment: You're probably seeing registry redirection, because you're not running as admin.

Comment: I ran it as Admin, but nothing happens.

Comment: I even ran it with no admin privileges, but still no errors when it supposed to show "access denied" or something.

Comment: Please provide a little more context: what version of .NET are you targeting? What is the build target architecture (x86, x64, Any CPU)? What OS are you running this on (7, 8, 10 / x86, x64)? UAC, no UAC? Also, what do you see when you run the program line by line?

What is the expected result? How do you check that something has or has not been written to the registry.

Aside: You don't really need to call `.ToString()` on those app settings, the indexer should already give you back a string.

Comment: I updated the question. I know I don't need to call ToString(). It was just a last resource after almost one hour trying to find a solution. :)

Comment: The example at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey uses the `using` construct. Have you tried using `using` instead of `Close()`? Not completely sure whether that would make any difference, but I would give it a try.

Comment: Have you tried using `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.***)` instead of `Registry.LocalMachine`? It allows you to specify which view you want (default, 32-bit or 64-bit), so you can find out if your problem has to do with registry redirection.

Comment: Is your program running as a 32-bit or 64-bit program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @PieterWitvoet in the comments, you might want to use [`OpenBaseKey()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey.aspx) instead. This is to avoid WoW64 registry redirection as explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384182.aspx

**Note the small print at the end of that page:**

> *To examine the effect of running this example with regedit, inspect the values of the following keys. Note that applications should avoid using Wow6432Node in hard-coded registry paths.*

So, here is an example of what you could be doing instead:

```
static void Edit()
{
    using (var root = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
    using (RegistryKey key = root.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Homebrew-Testing"))
    {
        key.SetValue("ServerName", "ServerName-Value");
        key.SetValue("ImageServerName", "ImageServerName-Value");
    }
}
```

Notice how you can ditch the second part of your code that deals specifically with `Wow6432Node`, which is recommended against in the article linked above.

The documentation for [`RegistryView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview.aspx) states that if you request the  64-bit view on a 32-bit operating system, the returned keys will be in the 32-bit view.

I hope this helps. Best of luck.